# Configuration of one SSD for multiple OS (Windows 11, ArchLinux) and another for data

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems, desktop-computer

I know in the era of SSDs the speed benefits of having a separate OS drive aren't there. But I've also heard that having a separate drive for OS files makes reinstallations much easier. I don't have much experience with dual-booting though.

- Would these benefits be preserved even if my OS drive holds multiple operating systems? (say Windows 11 and ArchLinux)
- Are there things I should look out for or a better configuration?

Comment: The reason for a separate data partition is mostly to avoid problems with Windows in a dual-boot. You shouldn't be writing to the Windows system partition from outside Windows. Other reason was price as large enough SSDs were very expensive but not so much today.

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer

This is not intended to explain to you how to set up your system, -as that would be required to run several commands for installation and configurations-, but to give you an idea of how you could structure your partition tables for both dual-boot and single-boot.

### My Hardware

Asus TUF F15 i5-10300H (model 2020)
RAM: 16 GB DDR4 (dual channel)
SSD #1: 512 GB NVMe M.2 2280
SSD #2: 500 GB NVMe M.2 2280

*Note: This laptop came with Windows 11 installed on `SSD #1`. I just added `SSD #2` and installed ArchLinux on it.*

**SSD #1: Windows 11**

| part label | part number | size | File System | Partition Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| System | 1 | 237 MB | FAT | EFI System |
|  | 2 | 17 MB | Unknown | MS Reserved |
| OS | 3 | 487 GB | NTFS | BAsic Data |
| Recovery | 4 | 999 MB | NTFS | MS W. Recovery |
| Retsore | 5 | 24 GB | NTFS | Basic Data |

**SSD #2: ArchLinux, kernel 6.2.10.arch1-1**

| Label | number | size | File System | Partition Type | Mount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| boot | 1 | 537 MB | FAT | EFI System | /boot |
| arch-root | 2 | 107 GB | Ext4 | Linux Filesystem | /root |
| arch-home | 3 | 54 GB | Ext4 | Linux Filesystem | /home |
| arch-data | 4 | 295 GB | Ext4 | Linux Filesystem | /data |
| test-lab | 5 | 43 GB | Ext4 | Linux Filesystem | N/A |

I follow the official ArchLinux [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide) in addition to other [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) entries for dual-boot installation. You just need to read, everything you need is there.

### About `SSD #2`

- `arch-root`: Here I installed the OS (ArchLinux)
- `arch-home`: Home directory mostly used for local packages and config files
- `arch-data`" In this partition I stored everything from pictures to videos, code repository and more.

The `arch-data` partition is mounted on boot to the `/data` mounting point. I gave my user privileges over that particular directory to avoid having to use `sudo` for writing operations.

I am using a *swap file* therefore, there is no need for a *swap partition*.

I hope it helps!